# Android-Voice recognition

Tags: android

I am new to android.I am working on voice recognition.I got a sample program

### main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/hello"
/>

<Button 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Speak"
android:id="@+id/speakButton"/>

<ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

/>      
</LinearLayout>
```

### VoiceRec:

```
public class VoiceRec extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private static final int VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

private ListView mList;

/**
 * Called with the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Inflate our UI from its XML layout description.
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Get display items for later interaction
    Button speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.speakButton);

    mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Check to see if a recognition activity is present
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(
            new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
    if (activities.size() != 0) {
        speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    } else {
        speakButton.setEnabled(false);
        speakButton.setText("Recognizer not present");
    }
}

/**
 * Handle the click on the start recognition button.
 */
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.speakButton) {
        startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
    }
}

/**
 * Fire an intent to start the speech recognition activity.
 */
private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speech recognition demo");
    startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
}

/**
 * Handle the results from the recognition activity.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Fill the list view with the strings the recognizer thought it could have heard
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        mList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                matches));
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

I got the output like

[image]

Please help out where i went wrong.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the output you should be getting based on your code.  You have asked it to disable the button and re-name it if there is no speech recognition available.  Speech recognition does not come standard with the Android SDK, you have to download and install an app to handle it.  See this thread: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/f11f7598ff60f4ae?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

For using RecognizerIntent device must have Google voice search because RecognizerIntent means an intent launched for using google voice listening engine.

Also,have you checked your internet connection ,it will not work if there is no wifi or net connection.
Don't forget permission

```
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```